# Transition between views as if one was modal

Tags: objective-c, ios, view

I've got a login screen I want to hide like:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:true];
```

But the problem is that I need to display it like this:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self presentModalViewController:loginScreen animated:false];
}
```

Which means I'll flash the current screen before I popup the login screen.

So what I'm looking for is a way to show the login screen instantly and transition to the main screen with the same animation as dissmissModalViewControllerAnimated:true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done (maybe not the best solution):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Initial set to hidden for avoiding a flickering UI
    self.view.hidden=YES;
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 block:^{
        [self presentModalViewController:self.loginViewController animated:NO];
    } repeats:false];

}
```

And just before you dispatch the ModalViewController you set `self.view.hidden=NO`.
See https://github.com/jivadevoe/NSTimer-Blocks for the NSTimer using blocks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just disable the animation so its instant?

```
[self presentModalViewController:loginScreen animated:NO];
```

Do it in viewWillAppear if it still flashes briefly.

Comment: OP is already doing the first thing. So your answer is "Do it in viewWillAppear".

Comment: Sorry, the animated:true part was a typo. But I cannot display it in the viewWillAppear because of this warning: 'Warning: Attempt to present <LoginViewController: 0x1cdc4390> on <MainViewController: 0x1cdb5220> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!'

Comment: And not because it gives me a warning, it also doesn't show me the login screen ;-)

Comment: Can you try presenting it after a delay so it executes on the next ui loop of the main thread - move the presentModal line to a new method, and then call: [self performSelector:@selector(presentModalMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];